# Scale Faces in UV/Image Editor

Tags: uv-image-editor

I want to scale a lot of faces in the UV/Image Editor, If I select all of them and scale them the center of every face moves.
Is there a way to scale all faces and keep their position, except selecting them seperately and scaling them down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This button in the UV editor is what you are looking for: [image]

Comment: You may need to edit the actual faces in 3D view to Edge Split all the faces first. Otherwise they will remain attached to each other when you scale.